# OneHot vectors with feature names

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn

Looking at the documentation of the [`OneHotEncoder`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html) there doesn't seem to be a way to include the feature names as a prefix of the OneHot vectors. Does anyone know of a way around this? Am I missing something?

Sample dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':['c1', 'c1', 'c2', 'c1', 'c3'], 'b':['c1', 'c4', 'c1', 'c1', 'c1']})

from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder

onehot = OneHotEncoder()
onehot.fit(df)

onehot.get_feature_names()
array(['x0_c1', 'x0_c2', 'x0_c3', 'x1_c1', 'x1_c4'], dtype=object)
```

Where given that the encoder is fed a dataframe I'd expect the possibility to obtain something like:

```
array(['a_c1', 'a_c2', 'a_c3', 'b_c1', 'b_c4'], dtype=object)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is what you need to do to include your feature names from [`get_feature_name`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html).

```
onehot.get_feature_names(input_features=df.columns)
```

Output:

```
array(['a_c1', 'a_c2', 'a_c3', 'b_c1', 'b_c4'], dtype=object)
```

Per docs:

> get_feature_name(self, input_features=None)
>   Return feature names for output features.
>
> Parameters:    input_features : list of string, length n_features,
>   optional String names for input features if available. By default,
>   “x0”, “x1”, … “xn_features” is used.
>
> Returns:   output_feature_names : array of string, length
>   n_output_features

Comment: Ahh so there is a way! Thanks @scott :)

Comment: For the exact reason, I have updated the example in documentation. Look at the dev version of the documentation [here](https://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html)

Answer (score 0):

Let's create a dataframe with 3 columns, each having some categorical values.

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder

df_dict= {'Sex' :['m', 'f' ,'m' ,'f'] , 'City' : ['C1' , 'C2' , 'C3' , 'C4'] , 'States' :['S1' , 'S2', 'S3', 'S4']}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(df_dict)
cat_enc = OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown = 'ignore')
transformed_array = cat_enc.fit_transform(df).toarray()
transformed_df = pd.DataFrame(transformed_array , columns= cat_enc.get_feature_names(df.columns))
transformed_df.head()
```

We will get the following output -

```
City_C1 City_C2 City_C3 City_C4 Sex_f   Sex_m   States_S1   States_S2   States_S3   States_S4
0   1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
1   0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0
2   0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0
3   0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0
```